# How to install .NET Core on aarch64 architecture Debian

Tags: c#, linux, debian, arm64

I'm new to Linux and want to code some C# on Linux for school. The problem is I don't know how to install C#. I already read the instructions from Microsoft, but I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: *I already read the instruction from Microsoft, but I don't get it* so what makes you think that you would understand answer here which prolly be the same as on MS website?

Comment: anyway seems like first you need to install snap then use snap to install dotnet or use dotnet-install.sh ...  where is the problem ?

Comment: First read [this article](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/learn/dotnet/what-is-dotnet). Then [Meet the Visual Studio family](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/). You may need to [Download .NET](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet)

Comment: Lots of information available — https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux (tldr; it’s likely easiest to use a *package* provided by the Linux distribution; the above article provides links for various major distributions)

Comment: For example, to install on Debian, it’s as simple as https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-debian .. (key setup, install SDK, install runtime)

Comment: I’ve used the instructions linked to by @user2864740 a number of times successfully. Including when `snap` made a mess of installing an update..

Answer (score 1):

'arm64' is the Debian port name for the 64-bit Armv8 architecture, referred to as 'aarch64' in upstream toolchains. The snapd daemon and tooling that enables snap packages is available for arm64 architecture in Debian.

To install snapd:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install snapd
```

Either log out and back in again or restart your system to ensure that snap's paths are updated correctly. After this install the core snap in order to get the latest snapd:

```
sudo snap install core
```

C# is open source and cross platform now that Microsoft has released a version of .NET Core. To install .NET Core in Debian open the terminal and type:

```
sudo snap install dotnet-sdk --classic
sudo snap alias dotnet-sdk.dotnet dotnet # to run dotnet-sdk type dotnet
```

The instructions from Microsoft seem to assume that you are running Visual Studio Code on Windows, so they frequently don't work at all on Linux. The following instructions were tested on a Debian-based system (Ubuntu 20.04). I ran a few C# console apps for test purposes, but let's start with a simple one-line C# console app. Run these commands to build and run an example C# Hello World  console app from the terminal:

```
cd ~
mkdir C#_Projects
cd C#_Projects
mkdir HelloWorld
cd HelloWorld
dotnet new console
dotnet build --output ./build_output  
dotnet ./build_output/HelloWorld.dll
```

Results of `dotnet ./build_output/HelloWorld.dll`

```
Hello, World!
```

Comment: You wrote in your question that you need to code some C# on Linux for school. Is your code a console app? If so you're done. If not you will probably need to install the Visual Studio Code snap package and the C# for Visual Studio Code (powered by OmniSharp) extension for Visual Studio Code in order to continue. Before installing more software please ask what software your teacher recommends. If C# in VSCode tries to take over Debiian like a hydra you're going to have to either make a Debian virtual machine and run it in a VM or ask for more help.